# How to input with method Post in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I have a code input in javascript code, but it's use method GET

```
$('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){ //on submit
    var judul   = document.getElementById("judul_survey").value;
    var kategori= document.getElementById("id_kategori").value;
    var target  = document.getElementById("viewSelector").value;
    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() ?>survey/simpan_survey?judul_survey="+judul+"&id_target="+target+"&id_kategori="+kategori;
}
```

I want to change with method Post, please help me.
**Note**: I've used the `$ _POST` method in its php process

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just post it?

Comment: You already are in a form submit event - why the window.location redirect? Just give the form the correct action and you are good to go

Comment: this is just a piece of code, actually it involves the datatables that require using javascript for its input

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you doing things like `document.getElementById("judul_survey").value;`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)** method to post data using `POST` method.

```
$('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){ 

    $.post("survey/simpan_survey",
      { judul_survey: judul, id_target: target }, 
     function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    })

   });
```